# Intermittent ping timeouts on GCE instances

Tags: google-compute-engine

These past 3 days, it seems I have network issues on my Google cloud engine instances. I investigate every single part of my architecture, and once it reaches my instances, everything responds lightning fast.

But still, from time to time, requests are stuck for 2 minutes.

I tried executing a long-running 'ping' to one of my instance. Here is the result:

```
64 bytes from 107.178.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=252 ttl=45 time=65.890 ms
64 bytes from 107.178.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=253 ttl=45 time=83.041 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 254
Request timeout for icmp_seq 255
Request timeout for icmp_seq 256
64 bytes from 107.178.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=257 ttl=45 time=65.925 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 258
64 bytes from 107.178.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=259 ttl=45 time=63.801 ms
64 bytes from 107.178.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=260 ttl=45 time=65.046 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 261
Request timeout for icmp_seq 262
Request timeout for icmp_seq 263
Request timeout for icmp_seq 264
Request timeout for icmp_seq 265
64 bytes from 107.178.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=266 ttl=45 time=75.441 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 267
64 bytes from 107.178.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=268 ttl=45 time=67.201 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 269
Request timeout for icmp_seq 270
Request timeout for icmp_seq 271
Request timeout for icmp_seq 272
Request timeout for icmp_seq 273
Request timeout for icmp_seq 274
64 bytes from 107.178.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=275 ttl=45 time=70.824 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 276
64 bytes from 107.178.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=277 ttl=45 time=81.096 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 278
Request timeout for icmp_seq 279
Request timeout for icmp_seq 280
Request timeout for icmp_seq 281
64 bytes from 107.178.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=282 ttl=45 time=61.271 ms
```

That does not look good to me.

Is there any way to contact Google when you have a problem with your instances? I just learned that by default I have a "bronze" support which actually means 0 support as I cannot contact anybody. I apparently need to pay $150/month to get someone answering my questions!!

I am quite surprise to pay for something and not having anybody on the other side if the service is not working properly. Am I missing something? Or should I just wait and pray?

Comment: Ping stats `5026 packets transmitted, 4693 packets received, 6.6% packet loss`

Comment: It may be related to this ongoing networking issue: https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/compute/15050 . We are still investigating the issue with Google Compute Engine Networking performance. We will provide another status update by 2015-04-12 22:00 US/Pacific.

Comment: The problem with Google Compute Engine Networking should be resolved as of 22:40 US/Pacific. Could you please confirm if issue is solved for you? Thank you.

Comment: It seems all OK this morning. However my problems started on April 11th around 1pm pacific time while this incident states that the problem started on April 12th. I will look closely at performances and will keep you posted if I notice anything. Is there a way to report an incident apart from stackoverflow?

Comment: I still have about 1.2% packet loss on each of my instances: `3420 packets transmitted, 3375 packets received, 1.3% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 54.573/64.828/131.441/5.518 ms` and `3420 packets transmitted, 3379 packets received, 1.2% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 54.486/64.737/135.931/5.880 ms`, this is way better, but still not sure the 1% loss is normal

Comment: It may happen that some routers may loss packet if when they are under heavy load or traffic.

To troubleshoot this issue I suggest you to:
- Use mtr tool to test connection TO your instance from different locations and ISP.
- Use mtr tool to test connectivity FROM your instance to some hosts in different locations.

Mtr tool should help identifying how much packets are loss and where.